# MDP FANode issues

Tags: python, analysis, factor-analysis

I'm trying to perform factorial analysis on a distance matrix (made of distances between about 1700 points, all ranging between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusively). I'm a total FA newbie.

Anyways, this code:

```
fan=mdp.nodes.FANode()
far=fan.execute(a)
# a is a numpy.array, size 1780x1780
```

Gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    far=fan.execute(a)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mdp/signal_node.py", line 575, in execute
    self._pre_execution_checks(x)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mdp/signal_node.py", line 451, in _pre_execution_checks
    self._if_training_stop_training()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mdp/signal_node.py", line 431, in _if_training_stop_training
    self.stop_training()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mdp/signal_node.py", line 556, in stop_training
    self._train_seq[self._train_phase][1](*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mdp/nodes/em_nodes.py", line 93, in _stop_training
    A = normal(0., sqrt(scale/k), size=(d, k)).astype(typ)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1279, in mtrand.RandomState.normal (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:6943)
ValueError: scale <= 0
```

I tried replacing 0 values with 0.00001, to no avail. Any idea what this might mean?

Comment: Which version of mdp are you using? In more recent versions a `scale <= 0` should have been caught by mdp and hinted ‘The covariance matrix of the data is singular. Redundant dimensions need to be removed.’.